# How to call sprite layer draw methods from different classes with desired depths?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, kinect, layer

I'm totally new to working with sprites.

I need to draw opaque sprite layers for a game interface. The methods for these draw calls are defined in two different classes:

```
public class ColorStreamRenderer : Object2D
{
    .
    .
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        .
        .
        this.Game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        this.SharedSpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.Additive);
        this.SharedSpriteBatch.Draw(this.backBuffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 960), null, Color.White);
        this.SharedSpriteBatch.End();
        .
        .
    }
```

and

```
public class AvateeringXNA : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    .
    .
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        .
        .
        private Texture2D recttex;
        .
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture, BlendState.Opaque);
        this.recttex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("doodle");
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture, BlendState.Opaque);
        spriteBatch.Draw(recttex, rightMenu[ID], Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();             
        .
        .
    }
```

`rightMenu[ID]` is a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle` which lies within the output display window.

These two classes have already inherited one class each, and since C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, I can't use `Content.Load` within the `ColorStreamRenderer` class. So the sprites need to be drawn in different classes.

Now, the problem is, I'm not able to control the depth of the sprites. No matter what parameters I pass, the sprites of class `AvateeringXNA` are always behind those of the `ColorStreamRenderer` class.
By tweaking the blending options on the screen, I know that these are actually drawn on the screen since the layers behind are partially visible.

I've tried all the overloads for `SharedSpriteBatch.Begin` and `SharedSpriteBatch.Draw`, none of them work. Even defining the depth explicitly by `layerDepth` parameter for `SharedSpriteBatch.Draw` and `spriteBatch.Draw` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than untangling your code, I'll give you the info that I think you need to solve this:

**First:** `SpriteBatch` (except in immediate mode) does all of its drawing inside the `End` call. It queues up all of its drawing so it can submit sprites to the GPU in *batches* (for performance). If you use its built-in sorting, it only sorts the sprites within its current queue (between begin and end).

*If possible*, it's best to just use a single begin/end block for your entire frame, and just `Draw()` everything in back-to-front order in the first place. But this isn't a requirement.

One neat trick is to treat `SpriteBatch` like a list of sprites to be rendered. Fill up multiple ones at once, then call `End` on them in the desired rendering order. (Handy if your objects' logical order doesn't match the desired rendering order.)

By default the only depth-sorting you get with `SpriteBatch` is if you use its sorting modes. But it can use the depth buffer (like 3D graphics) if you use `DepthStencilState.Default`. I wouldn't recommend it, though. The `layerDepth` parameter to `Draw` sets the Z position of a sprite (valid between 0 and 1).

**Second:** `Content` is just a property of `Game` of type `ContentManager`. You can take that `ContentManager` object and pass it into different classes and load things from within them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew! This solved my problem. I never realized that `Game` can be passed into multiple classes.

Comment: You're welcome :) I did mean pass `Content` itself around - but, yes, absolutely, you could pass your `Game` class around too, if that works better for your code. They're both reference types - so you're just giving out a reference to them.